# How to make the regula expression correct?

Tags: php, regex, php-7

I am not that familiar with regex or php, this line constantly return parsing error for detect email patterns:
     with preg_match with the following inside which I changed from ereg:
    if(!preg_match("/^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\|\")]{0,62}\"))$\", $local_array[$i])) 
and:
    if(!preg_match('/^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])\|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$/', $domain_array[$i]) )

I tried to add `/` before and after it `/` for the following, it seems ok.

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$
```

The rest says:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '","' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

How make it correct? It has parse errors when I switch from ereg to preg_match.

Thanks,
J.

Comment: A little more context, please.

Comment: adding a \ before `/=` in both places should get rid of the parse error. However, the regex doesn''t seem to be for email pattern

Comment: Post the PHP code itself, not just the regexp.

Comment: If you put `/` around the regexp, you need to escape all the `/` inside the regexp. It's best if you make the delimiter around the regexp a character that doesn't appear inside.

Comment: This one: !preg_match('/^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])\|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$/', $domain_array[$i]), how to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the validity of an e-mail according to the actual standard rather than just `"[0-9A-z]@[0-9A-z]\\.(?i:[A-Z])"` ?

Fantastic. As someone who uses a hyphen in their e-mail address, I wish there were more web-developers like you!

Here's the regex to match according to the RFC standard:

```
"/^([0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+|(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+\.\"(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~. (),:;<>@[]\E]+|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")+\"\.)+[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+|\"(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~. (),:;<>@[]\E]+|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")+\")@(?:[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+|\[[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+\])$/"
```

Yhikes. As you can see there are multiple parts to that pattern, and if-statement logic is much, much faster, and helps reduce the eye-sore of a pattern this is.

So, if you care about that sort of thing, I would recommend writing a function to check the e-mail address like so:

1) Check that neither the local or domain part of the e-mail address have leading, trailing, or consecutive dots, and that it is in the correct format. e.g.

```
if (!preg_match("/^\.|\.\.|\.@|@\.|\.$/",$email) && preg_match("/^[^@]+?@[^\\.]+?\..+$/",$email)) {
```

This ensures there is an '@' symbol for the next part, and if it fails here, saves what would have been a lot of unnecessary computing.

2) Tokenize the e-mail address by '@:'

```
$part = explode("@",$email);
```

3) Of course, there could be more than one '@,' so if the array has more than 2 elements, loop through each and re-concatenate all but the final element, so that you get two strings: the local part (before the mandatory '@') and the domain part.

4) If the first element/local part of the address does not contain any quotation marks (&#36;), then use this pattern:

```
$pattern = "/^[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+$/";
```

5) Else if the local part begins AND ends with quotation marks, use this pattern:

```
$pattern = "/^\"(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~. (),:;<>@[]\E]+|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")+\"$/";
```

5) Else if the local part contains TWO quotation marks (one only would invalidate), use this pattern:

```
$pattern = "/^(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+\.\"(?:[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~. (),:;<>@[]\E]+|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\")+\"\.)+[0-9A-Za-z\/\Q!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~.\E]+$/";
```

7) Else the first part is invalid.

8) If the local part was valid: If the second element/domain part is either encapsulated within square brackets ([]) or contains NO square brackets (you can just use `substr` and `substr_count` for this, since it will be much faster than regex), and it matches the pattern:

```
preg_match("/^\[?[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+\]?$/",$domainPart);
```

Then it is valid.

Note: According to the standard, e-mail addresses can actually contain comments (why, I have no idea). The comments are not actually part of the e-mail address, and get removed when it is used. For that reason, I didn't bother matching them.

Comment: This demonstrates your point admirably, but still doesn't validate an email address is valid. jane.simth@gmail.com passes pattern validation, but is not a valid email address because of the typo in the last name (should be "smith"). Validating an email address by pattern - other than superficially (say: got an @ in it) - is a fool's errand. One needs to validate the address by *using it*, and getting the recipient to confirm it. Anything else is just an increasing amount of waste of time, the more effort one puts into it. Nice regex pattern though.

Comment: "Valid" and "exist" are two different things. A typo will invalidate if it breaks compliance with the standard, but if not, it will still be valid. It may simply result in a non-existent or the "wrong" address. Your issue appears to be with the purpose of performing such validation. I've done this once before, in university, because validation of all fields was required, and you should aim to impress. Perhaps the OP is in the same boat, or perhaps he wishes to execute a routine every N days or weeks to clean "dead" records from his database? Who knows. You could always ask!